# Get TextView from list item which has been touched

Tags: android, listview

I want to get/set the value of a specific `TextView` of `list_item` but I cannot catch the `TextView`. My `list_item` is here:

```
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtProductName"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Product name"
            android:textColor="@color/Green"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtOrderQty"
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="60dip"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:text="0"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            />
    </RelativeLayout>


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtGenericName"
        android:textStyle="italic"
        android:layout_marginTop="-10dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Test"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="0dp" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="5"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <TextView
                style="@style/TextView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Code:" />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtProductCode"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="11111" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_weight="5"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <TextView
                style="@style/TextView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Pack:" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtPackSize"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="100gm" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_weight="5"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <TextView
                style="@style/TextView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="TP:" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtUnitPrice"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="0tk" />
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_weight="5"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <TextView
                style="@style/TextView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="VAT:" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtVat"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="0tk" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Setting `OnTouchListener` from Adapter's `getView()`.

```
listView.setOnTouchListener(new CountingTouchListener(listView, position, mContext, holder.orderQty));
```

This is my `onTouch()`:

```
public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
    try {
        touchAny(view);
        if(motionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN ){
            touchDown(motionEvent);
        }else if (motionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE){
            touchMove(view, motionEvent);
        }else if(motionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){
            touchUp(motionEvent);
        }

    }catch (Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}

    return false;
}


private void touchMove(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
        TextView tv = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtOrderQty);
        Log.i(TAG, "val: "+tv.getText().toString()); //gives me value of txtOrderQty from the list_item which is the first of current visible items
        Log.i(TAG, txtOrderQty.getText().toString()); //gives me value of txtOrderQty from the list_item which is the last of current visible items
}
```

When I scroll the list, 5 or 6 items are visible at a time. Among them I'm getting the first and the last. But I want the `TextView` from the item which has been touched.

Comment: do you have any specific requirement to implement this in touch? can't be it done from onItemClick listener or from inside the adapter clickListener?

Comment: Yes, I've to do in onTouch, as I'm receiving `ACTION_MOVE` when it's horizontal drag.

Comment: You can use `listView.setOnItemClickListener`

Comment: Can I get horizontal drag if I use `OnItemClickListener`?

Answer (score 0):

According to [developer.android.com](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.OnItemClickListener.html) :

> public abstract void onItemClick (AdapterView parent, View view,
>   int position, long id)
>
> Callback method to be invoked when an item in this AdapterView has
>   been clicked.
>
> Implementers can call getItemAtPosition(position) if they need to
>   access the data associated with the selected item.
>
> Parameters
>
> parent:   The AdapterView where the click happened.
>
> view:     The view within the AdapterView that was clicked (this will be
>   a view provided by the adapter)
>
> position:     The position of the view in the adapter. id:    The row id of
>   the item that was clicked.

You can call `listview.setOnItemClickListener(...)` and pass a `new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener` to the method and in the onItemClick method body which is explained above call:

```
view.findViewById(R.id.txtProductName)
```

to get the TextView within that item.

Comment: I've to do in onTouch, as I'm receiving `ACTION_MOVE` when it's horizontal drag.

Comment: @CoolBrain you can add them both. just when you are handling the move, in your onTouch method return true and other wise return false.

Comment: @CoolBrain and can you switch to recyclerview for god's sake? :)

Comment: will recyclerview solve my issue? (sorry for my late)